# Redis expiration replication to slaves

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am interested in using Redis to store a customer's session on the server side for authorization.  Basically, when a customer logs in a hash will be stored in a Redis cluster and the key returned to the client.  On each request, the client will pass the key as a header and the service will check that the hash still exists in Redis, if it doesn't then an error message will be returned.  This key will expire after X minutes resulting in any requests using that key to fail.  However, I have been reading online that some people experienced issues because of the way the expiration is replicated to slaves.  Slaves only expire a key when they receive a del command from the master so if a "get" is made on a slave before this command, the value at that key will be returned.

https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/187

Does this issue still exist?  It seems like a big issue to me and would create a bit of a security hole.  Maybe not a big deal for stale data but when using for authorization it is a big deal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) no, not really — since 2014, a GET of an expired key will return "not found" on a slave even if the slave hasn't yet received a DEL from the replication stream. The outstanding issue has to do with EXISTS being inconsistent with GET, which only matters if you rely on the output of the EXISTS command.

B) Completely independent of this issue, the possibility of replication lag always exists. The security of your app shouldn't depend on the premise that replicas are always up-to-date.